# What causes a control to be placed more left-right-top-bottom than another which has same alignment?

Tags: delphi, layout, alignment

I'm creating 2 buttons at runtime. 
Both have the same parent and same alignment:

```
var
   Btn : TButton;
begin
   Btn := TButton.Create(Self);
   Btn.Caption := 'ButtonA';
   Btn.Align := alLeft;
   Btn.Parent := Self;

   Btn := TButton.Create(Self);
   Btn.Caption := 'ButtonB';
   Btn.Align := alLeft;
   Btn.Parent := Self;
end;
```

Why one of them is displayed more left than the other one?

I mean, what determinate that ButtonB is displayed more left than ButtonA? (Why not vice versa?)

Comment: From help: `Any number of child components within a single parent can have the same Align value, in which case they stack up along the edge of the parent`

Comment: I mean, what determinate that ButtonB is displayed more left than ButtonA? (Why not vice versa?)

Comment: I guess this is determined in the tab order, but it could just as well be the order in which it is stored in the DFM.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, It is determined by the Left property in this case. if ButtonB Left is equal or less than ButtonA it goes "before", else "after".

Comment: @kobik: Ah, indeed, that makes sense. What if both have the same Left value? Or is that impossible, because alignment sets Left?

Comment: From peeking at `TWinControl.AlignControls` I think It's the combination of `Left` property and the index in the parent's `Controls` list (same as order of `Btn.Parent := Self;` assignments in this case).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, If the inserted control has the same Left value, it is inserted before the existing control. if I recall correctly (I don't have Delphi right now), it's even the combination of Left + Width. so if you want to make ButtonB to be inserted to the right you set its Left to be ButtonA.Left + ButtonA.Width. or even set it to MAXINT

Comment: @RudyVelthuis when they both has the same principal boundary - then is it FIFO principle, or like we rudy say it in Russia "the first one awake gets the shoes" :-)

Comment: Yes, so who is the first? Probably the first one in order in the DFM, as I said.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, The OP is creating the controls dynamically. no DFM streaming here. The DFM uses the same rules, but the adjusted Bounds are already stored.

Comment: @kobik: then it is of course "first come first served".